# Qt 4.8: how to have a QPushButton that looks like a QLabel?

Tags: python, qt, qt4.8

I want to draw a `QPushButton` (clickable etc), but have it look like a `QLabel`. (Another way to see this is I want a clickable label, ie a label that behaves like a button, but that seems more difficult.)

I have tried `button.setStyleSheet("QLabel")`, doesn't work.
Is there a way to tell the button to use another style class? or "steal" the style from `QLabel`?

If possible I would like to avoid redefining the whole style (I do not own the stylesheet, Qt is embedded inside a third-party application), unless this is trivial.

Edit: I ended up using @musicamante's stylesheet solution, to which I added `text-align: left` (buttons are centered, labels are not), and `:hover/:pressed` colors (cyan/blue looks like programmer-art, but serves the purpose :):

```
QPushButton {
    border: none;
    background: transparent;
    text-align: left;
    color: palette(window-text);
}
QPushButton:hover {
    color: cyan;
}
QPushButton:pressed {
    color: blue;
}
```

Comment: You need to set the stylesheet to remove borders, click effects, background colors etc. You can take a look at [QPushButton Stylesheet reference](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qpushbutton.html)  `button.setStyleSheet({'background-color: red; border: none; }')` And if you are using some application level global styles, then setting objectname of the button will also work fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Styling a button like a label is not usually suggested as it wouldn't make it clear its state, especially when the mouse button is pressed and released *outside* the button rectangle.

In any case, it's enough to set the `border` property to `none`, which will also remove the background. Just to be safe and consistent, you could make the background transparent (some style might override it) and ensure that the `WindowText` color role of the palette is used (instead of the `ButtonText` role):

```
button.setStyleSheet("""
    border: none;
    color: palette(window-text);
    background: transparent;
""")
```

Making a clickable label is not that hard, though, and has the benefit of allowing usage of rich text content, something that a QPushButton cannot do.

```
class ClickableLabel(QLabel):
    clicked = Signal()
    def mousePressEvent(self, event):
        super(ClickableLabel, self).mousePressEvent(event)
        if event.button() == Qt.LeftButton:
            self.clicked.emit()
```

Or, to provide consistency with the behavior of a button (as described above, a "click" is considered valid if the mouse button is released within the boundaries of the button rectangle):

```
class ClickableLabel(QLabel):
    clicked = Signal()
    def mouseReleaseEvent(self, event):
        super(ClickableLabel, self).mouseReleaseEvent(self, event)
        if event.button() == Qt.LeftButton and event.pos() in self.rect():
            self.clicked.emit()
```

Comment: This is a correct solution. But just a little comment about your claim "usage of rich text content, something that a `QPushButton` cannot do". Actually it is quite easy to have a rich-text inside `QPushButton`. You can just insert a `QLayout` inside an empty `QPushButton` and add a `QLabel` with rich-text into the layout. Yes, it is as simple as that! :)

Comment: @V.K. Theoretically yes, but there's a problem: unlike standard container widgets, QPushButton ignores the size hint/policy of its layout. So, not only the button won't be able to resize itself if the text requires it, but the text will actually be truncated *both* horizontally and vertically if it's too long. Then there's the problem of the layout default margins, which can truncate even a short text unless the layouts margin are set to 0. Subclassing QLabel just requires reimplementing the mouseReleaseEvent, it's simpler and more consistent with the standard QLabel behavior.

Comment: Have you tried? According to my testing everything works fine with layouts inside buttons. The button adjusts its size to the layout perfectly. And default layout margins can be changed by setting `QLayout::setContentsMargins()`. I have seen no problems with this approach whatsoever.

Comment: @V.K. Yes, I obviously tried. And yes, it can work fine with all adjustments, but, as said, I don't see the benefit of trying to subclass an object that embeds other two objects and require that many precautions and modifications while it's enough to add a basic function reimplementation.

Comment: I am not talking about subclassing, I am talking about composition. You do not need sublassing if you want to put rich-text into button with the method I suggested. And if you do not understand the benefits of composition over inheritance, then you should probably get more experience programming. :)

Comment: @V.K. I thought you were suggesting subclassing, my bad. In any case, I just made another test (no subclassing, just composition :-) ), and I can confirm what I thought: adding the label to the layout of the button does *not* update the button size with those required by the label. And it shouldn't: `minumumSizeHint()` returns the `sizeHint()` of the button, which completely ignores the fact that it could have a layout, and it's only based on the style computations. I only tested on Linux, but I doubt it would make any difference, with PyQt4 (as OP requests) and PyQt 5.7/5.13.

Comment: @V.K. A *possible* solution could be to "patch" the `sizeHint` of the button with those of the label: `button.sizeHint = label.sizeHint`, possibly *before* adding the button to a layout. In any case, this is the test demonstrating the issue https://gist.github.com/MaurizioB/faedf525b4beb8910d3d25ebff66b984. Can you show how you managed to get your tests working?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a custom QLabel, first public inherit a QLabel, then overload the
`void mouseReleaseEvent(QMouseEvent *e)`

```
void mouseReleaseEvent(QMouseEvent *e){
    if(e.button == Qt::LeftButton){
          //emit a signal or you want to do when the label are clicked
    }    
}
```